# Linking two related records in the same table, and giving them ID's (SQL)

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Table "Observation" is filled with records, that come from table "Result" (observation_id = result_id)

In table "Observation" every record has a corresponding record that is also in the same table. Is there a way to link those two records, giving them their associated id. Tried a number of things but without any luck. Anyone care to take a look?

Current "Observation" table:

| observation_id pk | related_observation_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 |  |
| 8451 |  |
| 2 |  |
| 8452 |  |
| 3 |  |
| 8453 |  |

"Result" table:

| result_id pk | value | linking_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 234 | 1 |
| 8745 | 231 | 1 |
| 2 | 653 | 2 |
| 8746 | 318 | 2 |
| 3 | 774 | 3 |
| 8747 | 321 | 3 |

Desired "Observation" table:

| observation_id pk | related_observation_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 8745 |
| 8745 | 1 |
| 2 | 8746 |
| 8746 | 2 |
| 3 | 8747 |
| 8747 | 3 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this will do the update:

```
update observation o
set
  related_observation_id = r2.result_id
from result r1, result r2
where
  o.observation_id = r1.result_id and
  r1.linking_id = r2.linking_id and
  r2.result_id != o.observation_id and
  o.related_observation_id is null
```

However some warnings...

Is it always 1:1, so two observations per linking id?  If not, this will somewhat arbitrarily assign the value.  If you have a preference, what would it be?

Alternatively, you can list all related observation ids, but you would need to change your datatype.

Answer (score 0):

using self join and condition like this:

```
select 
     r1.result_id as observation_id
   , r2.result_id as related_observation_id
from result_table r1
left join result_table r2 
  on (r1.result_id = r2.linking_id or r2.result_id = r1.linking_id)
  and r1.result_id <> r2.result_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
     r1.result_id AS observation_id
   , r2.result_id AS related_observation_id
FROM result_table r1
LEFT JOIN result_table r2 
  on r1.result_id = r2.linking_id 
WHERE observation_id <> related_observation_id
```